# Prime Space - straight lines only connect primes?

Tags: analysis, number-theory

I was reading a very obscure article printed out at my university's library, and there was a topic which I wish to discuss a bit further.

That is, the author defined a space, namely $\mathbb{P}$, the space in which the only straight lines are formed by the connection of two or more primes. That is, in essence, $d(p_1,p_2)= p_1-p_2$ iff $p_1,p_2$ are prime, for an appropriate metric on this space.

My question is as follows: is this space even a feasible space? Does is even make any sense? Does it appear to have any use whatsoever? It seems the author believes that such a space could give insight to prime distribution

Comment: That author defined the "space" $\;\Bbb P\;$ ...as *what kind* of space? A general topological, metric, vector, whatever space? You seem to be giving some kind of a metric there, but we don't even know what that "space" $\;\Bbb P\;$ contains: only the positive primes? All the primes in the integers? Something else? It's hard to consider such a question without knowing waaaay more than what you wrote.

Comment: @timbuc I don't have the paper in front of me, but I believe it was supposed to be a type of Hilbert space, containing all real numbers, but with the notion of a straight line being defined between primes in the integers.. So yes, a space with defined norm and metric. I suppose the question is most concerning the feasibility of what it means to only have straight lines connect primes in the integers

Comment: @timbuc I suppose I'm trying to discern whether this is something that's a mathematical paper of hippity hoopla nonsense, or something to be seriously considered

Comment: I think it is clear your last comment's question cannot be reasonably answered without reading first hand that paper you talk about. In 1955, Hillel Furstenberg gave a rather original prove of the infinity of primes by introducing a rather easy, clear topology on $\;\Bbb Z\;$ . Who knows what that author and his paper are trying to do and achieve.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, please find the reference to this paper and post it, however obscure the reference may be. That will let us judge the content by its own weight.